# session data for mvc login with angular 2 app

Tags: asp.net-mvc, angular, asp.net-mvc-4, angular2-services

We have an MVC login site that loads an angular 4 app once successfully logged in.  We are using mvc controllers, which have a session manager that holds user data.  What's the best way for my angular 2 app to get and hold this data?  Currently I have a global service with UserId and UserStatus.  The UserStatus is needed to control access to parts of the site, which includes hiding or showing some of the navigation menu links.

The problem is that the calls are not completed before the page renders, so the menu doesn't get updated and the site's home page shows all controls.  If I click to another page then come back the site's home page is correctly hiding parts based on the user's status.  I created a simple plnkr that seems to simulate it.  https://plnkr.co/edit/NHgoMi?p=preview

I added a setTimeout variable to to simulate the delay of getting data from the server.  Notice that the one with the setTimeout has not completed before the page loads, so it displays the wrong value.

Is there a way to delay the app loading or the home component from rendering till the permissions are retrieved from the server?

here are the plnkr files:

main.ts:

```
    import {platformBrowserDynamic} from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic';
    import {AppModule} from './app';

    import { SessionService } from './session.service'; 

    platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(AppModule, [SessionService])
```

app.ts

```
    import {Component, NgModule, VERSION} from '@angular/core'
    import {BrowserModule} from '@angular/platform-browser'

    import {SessionService } from './session.service';

    import { LayoutModule } from './layout.module';


    @Component({
      selector: 'my-app',
      template: `
        <div>
          <h2>Hello {{name}}</h2>
          <layout></layout>
        </div>
      `,
      providers:[
        SessionService
      ]
    })
    export class App {
      name:string;
      constructor() {
        this.name = `Angular! v${VERSION.full}`
      }
    }

    @NgModule({
      imports: [ 
        BrowserModule,
        LayoutModule
        ],
      declarations: [ App ],
      bootstrap: [ App ]
    })
    export class AppModule {}
```

home.componenet.ts

```
    import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
    import { NgControl } from '@angular/forms';

    import { SessionService } from './session.service';


    @Component({
        selector: 'home',
        template: '<p>userStatus: {{userStatus}}</p><p>userStatusWithTimeout: {{userStatusWithTimeout}}</p>'
    })

    export class HomeComponent implements OnInit {

        userStatus: boolean;
        userStatusWithTimeout: boolean;

        constructor(private _sessionService: SessionService) {
        }

        ngOnInit(): void {
            this.userStatus = this._sessionService.getUserStatus();

            this.userStatusWithTimeout = this._sessionService.getUserStatusWithTimeout();
        }
    }
```

layout.componenet.ts

```
    import { Component } from '@angular/core';
    import { NgControl } from '@angular/forms';

    @Component({
        selector: 'layout',
        template: '<home></home>'
    })

    export class LayoutComponent {}
```

layout.module.ts

```
    import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
    import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';

    //components
    import { HomeComponent } from './home.component';
    import { LayoutComponent } from './layout.component';


    @NgModule({
        imports: [
            BrowserModule
        ],
        declarations:
        [
            HomeComponent,
            LayoutComponent
        ],
        exports: [
            LayoutComponent,
            HomeComponent
        ],
        providers: [
        ]
    })

    export class LayoutModule {}
```

session.service.ts

```
    import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
    import { Http, Response } from '@angular/http';
    import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
    import 'rxjs/Rx';

    @Injectable()
    export class SessionService { // extends ServiceAdapter {

        private _userStatus: boolean = false;
        private _userStatusWithTimeout: boolean = false;
        private _userID: number;
        private _getSessionUserID = 'Session/GetSessionUserID';
        private _getIsSessionUserStatus = 'Session/GetIsSessionUserStatus';

        constructor() {

            this.setSessionVariables();
        }

        setSessionVariables() {

            this.loadUserID()
                .do(data => console.log("loading id: ", data))
                .subscribe(result => this._userID = result);

            this.loadUserStatus()
                .do(data => console.log("loading status: ", data))
                .subscribe(result => this._userStatus = result);

            this.loadUserStatusWithTimeout()
                .do(data => console.log("loading status with timeout: ", data))
                .subscribe(result => this._userStatusWithTimeout = result);
        }

        loadUserID(): Observable<number> {
            return  Observable.of(setTimeout(() => { 1 }, 1000))  // this.getaction<number>(this._getSessionUserID);
        }

        loadUserStatus(): Observable<boolean> {
            return Observable.of(true)   //this.getaction<number>(this._getIsSessionUserStatus);
        }

        loadUserStatusWithTimeout(): Observable<boolean> {
          console.log("setting temp", this._userStatusWithTimeout);
          setTimeout(() => { this._userStatusWithTimeout = true }, 1000)
          console.log("temp is set", this._userStatusWithTimeout); 

            return Observable.of(this._userStatusWithTimeout)   //this.getaction<number>(this._getIsSessionUserStatus);
        }

        getUserID(): number {
            return this._userID;
        }

        getUserStatus(): boolean {
            return this._userStatus;
        }

        getUserStatusWithTimeout(): boolean {
            return this._userStatusWithTimeout;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Why don't subscribe to your observables and use NgIf (https://angular.io/api/common/NgIf) when you get actual data?

Comment: This is what it currently does.  The home screen is a dashboard that loads multiple components and once the user's status if updated the components disappear or show after the screen has loaded.

Answer (score 1):

Rather than hiding the restricted UI once you fetch the session data, reveal the restricted UI once you can verify the user should see it. This will prevent controls that a user shouldn't see from flashing and disappearing. If this creates some jank when new elements appear, consider a loading state that designs around it.

The most basic implementation of a loading state in Angular is to set an `isLoading` flag to true on a component or service when the request starts, then false when it finishes. Then put an `*ngIf='service.isLoading'` on an element in your template and *voila*.
Here's a bare-bones example of one I made for a pagination service: [service](https://github.com/SpaceFozzy/laravel-angular-pagination/blob/master/angular-client/src/app/basic-pagination/basic-pagination.service.ts) / [template](https://github.com/SpaceFozzy/laravel-angular-pagination/blob/master/angular-client/src/app/basic-pagination/basic-pagination.component.html) / [result](http://demo1.robotmonster.ca/laravel-angular/basic-pagination).

Also, if you are serving your Angular application with your MVC framework, it's possible to embed your permissions as a JavaScript object in the window of Angular's index page to make them immediately available to your app's permission/session service. This will avoid any loading delay while you fetch permissions, but will take additional configuration to get your server code working in the Angular launch page.

Comment: How do I create a loading screen for some components while they get data?  I saw examples of sending data into the angular app through ElementRef, but it seemed to be discouraged because of security risks.

Comment: I've updated my answer to include direction on a loading state with an example :) Not sure about passing data with ElementRef but anything you send to the client is inherently insecure.

Comment: Thanks for the help on this.  I tried the loading screen for my components that needed the permissions values, but they seemed inconsistent on waiting till they had all data b/f reduring the view.  To prevent the delay to the server when the app loads, I have my mvc index page save the values in the sessionstorage then my sessionservice gets the values as the app loads.  Thanks again for the help.

Comment: Glad to help! If my answer wasn't able to solve your problem directly could I humbly request an upvote if you found it in any way useful? Cheers.